# (django) static file for the whole project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-static

When I use `{% load static %}` and then add an image like this to my template:

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}">
```

I only get the image if it's stored in a direction called `static` which is in the same app. But I want to use the logo *for the whole project, and, also in a template for the whole project*. It doesn't work when the image is stored in a `static` direction which is in the inner project folder.

---

How do I use static files for the whole project? And how to acces them from the template? (I'm a hobby developper and so not in production ;-))
My settings are nearly the one they were when I created the project. (I only added some additional template direction.)

---

Thank you for reading this

Comment: What you say isn't true. Static files are accessible by any template. Please show your static settings and the layout of your project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use **static files** in your `Django project`, you have to realize several steps :

**Step 1 : INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py**

Make sure that you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

**Step 2 : STATIC_URL**

Then, in settings.py file you have to write this : `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Now, in your Django application, you can create a new repository named `static` and put your static elements inside.

If you want to call on of this element :

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

**STEP 3 (What do you want) : STATICFILES_DIRS**

If you have some static elements which are not for a particular Django application, you can use `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

You can create a new repository beside Django applications repository : `static`.

You will get :

```
My_project
|
 __ application 1
|
 __ application 2
|
 __ ...
|
 __ static
```

In settings.py file, please add :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'path_to_static_directory/static/',
]
```

Now, you can access to static files in any templates just by loading static files : `{% load static %}`.

Please, read this tutorial : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/